# measuring time in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Is there a way to implement something like this

```
while time left
  do something
```

where time is some variable set to x secs/minutes/hours in racket?

I could use some-constant to simulate time as in

```
(define (loop time)
   (if (< time some-constant)
       ((do something)
       (loop (- time 1)))
       do-nothing))
```

but I would have to experiment to see what constant would give me one hour, etc.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(define (loop term-time)
  (when (<= (current-seconds) term-time)
        (begin <do something>
               (loop term-time))))
```

Then you can invoke this with

```
(loop (+ (current-seconds) (* 60 60))) -- do it for one hour
```

If you just want to `<do something>` periodically, but doesn't want to do it at 100% CPU usage, in `<do something>`, you can include `(sleep <secs>)` to achieve this.